# Can't find run button in vs code with only my javascript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I've reinstalled Code runner for several times and I've test with many languages like python and c++ they are all work well (the run button on the top right corner was appear) but only for my js file the button disappear (I've tried to save the file for many times already)

Previously it was appear but I've accidentally right click on it and click on some option and it disappear =="

what should I do to recover that button again?

Answer (score 1):

if you right click the top right of your editor below the window options and select "run code" in the drop down, the button should reappear.

if it doesn't for whatever reason, you could run your code using `node index.js`.